# When shaking my MacBook I hear a strange sound, like a wobble

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

I recently bought a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015).

When I shake it vertically, some slow sounds come from it and it sounds like something wobbles in it.

Is this normal?

Comment: Same thing to mine. I don't know what happen. It's never been dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Macbook Pro should not be making any noise when you shake it, but there are a few things it could be: either the screen is moving ever so slightly or the internal fan is just moving when you shake it. If it is neither of those things (which the fan thing is unlikely so you have to decipher wether or not is it the screen) I would take it into an Apple store. It is most likely a minor issue like a loose screw or the like but if it is under warranty and there is an Apple store near by there is no harm.

Comment: If the sound came from screen, what should i do? Is something wrong?

Comment: As long as the screen feels like its not broken or loose then you should be fine. The screen will tend to move if you shake it with all laptops (my Yoga 2 Pro does that) even the MacBooks with their fancy hinges.

Comment: Same thing to mine. I don't know what happen. It's never been dropped.

Comment: I have a friend just recently bought here new macbook pro and it doesn't have any wobble when I shake it.

Answer (score -1):

Sameee!!!! I went to the Apple Store and they said there is nothing wrong. They even told me to shake the in-store ones to prove to me, but they don't have the sound. Apparently, its part of the "moving mechanisms". Which is BS

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please don't add comments in the _Answer_ field as this is for answers to questions. If you have a different question, ask it by clicking on [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Once you have enough [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you can also add a [bounty](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to get more users interested in the question. You can also read [how to ask a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting a good answer.